# Cannot load media static file photo anymore after pushing to heroku a number of times

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment, django-staticfiles

At the beggining it was fine to login but now after a number of times logging in and pushing changes to heroku, the static files stopped working. The error itself is "FileNotFoundError at /accounts/login/
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/media/profile_pics/obama.jpg'"

Initially i thought it was the ""  provided by the Login html django auth. This should redirect me to the index page.

.settings.py

```
  # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')


    # Deployment configs

    # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/
    PROJECT_ROOT   =   os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    STATIC_ROOT  =   os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

    # Extra lookup directories for collectstatic to find static files
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '/static'),
    )

    #  Add configuration for static files storage using whitenoise
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

    # update the db
    import dj_database_url
    prod_db  =  dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
    DATABASES['default'].update(prod_db)
```

I expected after logging in to be redirected to the index page but I get Filenotfound error even though theres no call function for any filetype. My instinct is that heroku doesnt keep static files so how can i make sure it keeps.

Comment: You cannot store uploaded images on the Heroku file system, because it is ephemeral.

Comment: Thanks i figured out! How can i close this question?